# How to write a SQL query to render the following data by channel and programs played?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm stuck with a query logic, please find the image for the table structure. I have two tables where one table is User which says about the user which tv channel he viewed on what period of time, there is another table where we have list of all the channel where for a given date we have all the programs that are played.

I need to explode the user table with the channel table where between the user, channel on the given time what are the programs played.

[image]

Comment: You have explained what you need but have not provided any indication of the efforts you have made.

Comment: What is the expected results? what you mean by _explode the user table_?

Comment: It would be better if you provided some DDL and sample data as SQL script

Comment: oh u need that one too, okey! so what I actually did was I find the difference between the program start and end time in the channel table did a cumulative sum(in sec) so per day, so the day starts with 0 to 86400s and then I did a cumulative sum. between start and the time from user table, the issue is if the programs end before few seconds and when I use between on cumulative sum I will be leaving behind one data and same goes of the end part. this is one of may things I'm trying. so that is that I'm now simply sitting and posting post and getting ans. Also thanks for the reply.! :) Peace

Comment: Firstly, you should provide the expected output as a table, not just a vague description of it. Secondly, _"I'm stuck with a query logic"_ is not a problem description: what did you try? where did you get stuck? did you get any specific errors?

Comment: I have tried to replace the title with something more useful - please review it and edit it again if necessary. "Please help me with logic" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you please check the results of following SELECT statement

```
select
*,
case 
    when ( u.starttime <= c.start and u.endtime >= c.[end])
    then datediff(mi, c.start,c.[end]) 
    when ( c.start <= u.starttime and c.[end] >= u.endtime)
    then datediff(mi, u.starttime,u.endtime) 
    when (u.endtime between c.start and c.[end]) 
    then datediff(mi, c.start, u.endtime) 
    when (c.[end] between u.starttime and u.endtime) 
    then datediff(mi, u.starttime,c.[end]) 
    end as period
from  [user] u
inner join channel c
    on  u.channel = c.channel and (
        u.starttime between c.start and c.[end] or
        u.endtime between c.start and c.[end] or 
        ( u.starttime <= c.start and u.endtime >= c.[end]) or
        ( c.start <= u.starttime and c.[end] >= u.endtime)
        )
```

Here is metadata script that could be used for solution

```
  create table [user] (
  name varchar(10),
  aga int,
  channel varchar(10),
  starttime time,
  endtime time
  )
    create table channel (
  channel varchar(10),
  title varchar(10),
  [start] time,
  [end] time
  )

insert into [user] select 'a',12,'abc','0:10','0:15'
insert into [user] select 'a',12,'abc','0:16','1:00'  
insert into [user] select 'a',12,'xyz','1:10','1:30'
insert into [user] select 'a',12,'xyz','1:40','1:50'
insert into [user] select 'a',12,'xyz','2:20','2:40'
insert into [user] select 'a',12,'xyz','2:40','3:00'
insert into [user] select 'a',12,'abc','5:30','6:40'
insert into [channel] select 'abc','a','0:00','0:12'
insert into [channel] select 'abc','b','0:12','0:15'
insert into [channel] select 'abc','c','0:15','0:30'
insert into [channel] select 'abc','1','0:30','0:55'
insert into [channel] select 'abc','2','0:45','1:15'
insert into [channel] select 'abc','3','5:00','5:35'
insert into [channel] select 'abc','4','5:35','6:35'
insert into [channel] select 'abc','5','6:35','7:35'
insert into [channel] select 'abc','6','7:35','7:45'
insert into [channel] select 'abc','7','7:45','8:45'

insert into [channel] select 'xyz','1','1:00','2:00'
insert into [channel] select 'xyz','2','2:00','2:10'
insert into [channel] select 'xyz','3','2:10','2:40'
insert into [channel] select 'xyz','4','2:40','3:00'
insert into [channel] select 'xyz','5','3:00','3:45'
insert into [channel] select 'xyz','6','3:45','3:50'

insert into [channel] select 'esk','N','2:00','3:00'
insert into [user] select 'M',10,'esk','1:00','4:00'
```

Comment: What if the user starts at 1pm, then a channel record lasts from 2pm to 3pm, and then the user records terminates at 4pm?

Comment: Over-lapping time ranges are defined with : `WHERE u.starttime < c.end AND u.endtime > c.start`

Comment: Your CASE statement fails for similar reasons.  The period is defined as `DATEDIFF(mi, GREATEST(u.starttime, c.start), LEAST(u.endtime, c.end))`

Comment: @MatBailie, you are right. I modied for that case in WHERE clause

Comment: @Eralper Thanks you very much man! I'm looking on the on condition I'm getting the expected output, still I'm looking on the duration part calculation in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ranges overlap when each starts before the other ends `WHERE a.start < b.cease AND b.start < a.start`

The start of the overlap is then the highest value of the two starts, and the cease of the overlap is the lowest of the two ceases.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN c.start > u.start THEN c.start ELSE u.start END   overlap_start,
    CASE WHEN c.cease < u.cease THEN c.cease ELSE u.cease END   overlap_cease,
    *
FROM
    user_viewing        u
INNER JOIN
    channel_schedule    c
        ON  c.channel_id = u.channel_id
        AND c.start      < u.cease
        AND c.cease      > u.start
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd02e/3

The important case to bear in mind when testing are covered int he SQLFiddle:
- `a` starts and ceases before `b` even starts
- `a` starts before `b` starts , and ends during `b`
- `a` starts and ceases during `b`
- `a` starts during `b` and ceases after `b` ceases
- `a` starts and ceases after `b` ceases
- `a` starts before `b` starts and ceases after `b` ceases

```
           |-------A------->

|--1--> |--2--> |--3--> |--4--> |--5-->
        |----------6---------->
```